# How to get 2-LOOKAHEAD results in this grammar?

Tags: compilers

```
G:
S -> bRS | RcSa | @(epsilon)
R -> acR | b

....

2-LOOKAHEAD(S->@) = {$,a,aa}
2-LOOKAHEAD(R->b) = {b,ba,bb,bc}
```

I don't understand a result of these rules..

----+

when I tried to solve `2-LOOKAHEAD(S->bRS)`, it solve easily.( `{ba,bb}` ).

but I don't understand why `2-LOOKAHEAD(S->@)` results are `{$,a,aa}` and

`2-LOOKAHEAD(R->b)` are `{b,ba,bb,bc}`. Please explain how to get these results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get LL Parser 2-LOOKAHEAD results in this grammar?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50487/how-to-get-ll-parser-2-lookahead-results-in-this-grammar)

Comment: I'll repeat the feedback I gave on the earlier copy of this question: "Please edit the question to clarify (a) ... (b) what you have tried or what research you have done (have you looked in standard textbooks?).  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.".  Also, please don't delete a question and re-post the same exact question.